# Maven dependency not working with springMVC project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have created a simple helloWorld maven dependency and placed that in my springmvc projects `pom.xml` but while deploying its showing bean creation exception of that `helloWorld: not` a qualified bean.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
Here how my dependent project looks like
My Application.java
package com.test

```
    @Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.test"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("hai");
            SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
            app.run(args);
        }
}
My Controller

    package com.test.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import test.Application;
import test.controller.Check;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Rest")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    Check check; // this is the bean from that dependency

    @RequestMapping(value="/logs",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logs(){

        return "I am the controler";
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>waffleTalentpool</groupId>
<artifactId>waffleTalentpool</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>server-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dblock.waffle</groupId>
        <artifactId>waffle-jna</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dblock.waffle</groupId>
        <artifactId>waffle-tomcat8</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    **<dependency>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>** // This is my maven dependency for standalone java application

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

My web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>waffleTalentpool</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TP</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.test.Application</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TP</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/tp/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My source code link 
[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5YL5NDA88_1U0NJYlZKa3BZbkU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: provide more details - logs, configurations, etc

Comment: most likely the problem is not in project dependencies, but in missing bean

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added my codes also in my question

Answer (score 0):

Your project structure does not follow maven standards.I updated the structure and uploaded here. Please try and let me know if that works

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3qylcHD3O-ddjVJLXRuOF9zM1U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The above answer is about spring boot application. you need to make a small change to your Application.java to make the war application work. Change to add extra package test to the @ComponentScan({"com.test","test"}) annotation